# Regex on second occurrence only

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible to perform my Regex on the second occurrence of a specific symbol only?

Regex being used:

```
@.*
```

Example data:

```
Stack@overflow:Stack@overflow
```

Desired output:

```
Stack@overflow:Stack
```

As you can see in the output, everything including and after the second occurrence of an `@` has been removed, but the text before it stays.

I'm using Notepad++ or any text editor which allows Regex's to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `@.*` will match the first occurrence of `@` and will then match any char except a newline until the end of the string and the dot will also match all following `@` signs.

If if `:` should also be a boundary, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any char except  `@` or `:`

```
[^@:]+@[^@:]+:[^@:]+
```

- `[^@:]+` Match any char except `@` or `:`
- `@` Match literally
- `[^@:]+` Match any char except `@` or `:`
- `:` Match literally
- `[^@:]+` Match any char except `@` or `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2KiYWN/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/xUfdT1/2/)

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\K@.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  @             # literally @
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Given:**

```
Stack@overflow:Stack@overflow
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Stack@overflow:Stack
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
regex = /(.*?@.*?)@.*/;
```

or just

```
(.*?@.*?)@.*
```

[link to solution](https://regex101.com/r/qJ0eU0/1)